# Qual a diferença do ng new e do ng generate application?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Eu sei que o `ng new nome-projeto` cria um diretório com o projeto dentro, mas não estou conseguindo entender a diferença entre ele e o `ng generation application`.

Na documentação do Angular e dito que o argumento `application`:

> Gera uma nova definição básica de aplicativo na subpasta "projetos" da área de trabalho.

Esse comando modifica os arquivos do projeto ou cria um novo projeto?

Notei que ele só funciona na pasta do app angular mas quais são as outras diferenças e quando usar cada um deles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng new` - cria uma nova solução angular do zero, com um projeto dentro e suas dependências e seus arquivos necessários, como o angular.json e etc.

já o `ng generation application` ou simplesmente `ng g application` criar um novo "projeto" dentro do sua "solução", então seu angular.json terá referencia dos dois projeto criado.

Você pode ter quantos projetos achar necessário e será compartilhado o node_modules.

Ao roda o comando `ng g application [nome]` você verá que será criado uma nova pasta com o nome do projeto e dentro dela, toda estrutura angular que você já conhece, menos os angular.json e outros arquivos que ficará na raiz do "solução".

Esse link explica melhor sobre as "soluções" ou espaço de trabalho como dito no artigo em inglês https://medium.com/@angularlicious/angular-6-workspace-test-drive-cfe24bbceeb3

Nunca trabalhei em projeto que necessitasse dessa estrutura, talvez em projetos mais robustos como GMAIL necessite.